# Can a differential equation with external input be rewritten to a form without external input?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question originates from a [C++ implementation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698011/is-there-a-c-ode-solver-that-assumes-exogenous-inputs-to-systems?noredirect=1#comment76379622_44698011) I had with ODE solvers.

Is there a way to rewrite

$$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),t)+g(u(t),t)$$

into

$$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),t)$$

given a known $u(t)$ in the time interval going from $t_0=0$ to $t_f$?

What comes to my mind is that I could redefine $u(t)$ as part of $x(t)$, but that would constrain the evolution of the value of $u(t)$ to predefined dynamics. I could then play with dynamics and initial values to make the system respond to a *pseudo*-input, which is in reality a state of the system. This is however too ugly a work-around for my C++ implementation.

Are there better ways to reshape the problem?

Comment: I don' t see what you want to implement here. You have an ODE $x'(t) = F(x(t),u(t),t)$, where $F(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ and $u(\cdot)$ are externally given. You can even make $u$ a part of $F$, hence the system is, essentially, $x'(t)=F_u(x(t),t)$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I'm asking how to make $u$ a part of $F$. The only way I thought of is what I described. So, how would you transform $F$ into $F_u$?